# Wanted output layer loss doesn't appear in caffe prints

Tags: caffe

I'm fine-tuning an existing network, adding one output layer of my own.
The network i'm using is already tuned to recognize faces and extract the facial features.

My added layer is only added to the last part (i'm hoping there is still enough data left there), trying to extract the yaw angle.

The end of the prototxt file before my changes:

```
layer {
  name: "cls_prob"
  type: "Softmax"
  bottom: "fc6_3"
  top: "cls_prob"
}
layer {
  name: "bbox_reg_3"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc5_3"
  top: "bbox_reg_3"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 3
  }
}
layer {
  name: "rotate_reg_3"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc5_3"
  top: "rotate_reg_3"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1
  }
}
```

Same segment with my changes + training changes:

```
layer {
  name: "cls_prob"
  type: "Softmax"
  bottom: "fc6_3"
  top: "cls_prob"
}
layer {
  name: "bbox_reg_3"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc5_3"
  top: "bbox_reg_3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 3
  }
}
layer {
  name: "rotate_reg_3"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc5_3"
  top: "rotate_reg_3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "yaw_reg_3"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc5_3"
  top: "yaw_reg_3"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "yaw_reg_3"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

I've added yaw_reg_3, but i only see rotate_reg_3, bbox_reg_3, and cls_prob loss prints.

Thanks

Comment: is it possible you already have another layer with `name: "loss"`? please provide the log output of your net construction so we can see what you mean by "loss doesn't appear in caffe prints"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging caffe itself with gdb:
After going over all the layers, if a layer doesn't appear as a bottom layer for another layer, it is determined as an output layer.
Since "yaw_reg_3" is the bottom for "loss", it is technically not an output layer, so only the loss for it is printed, and not the prediction itself.